# How to change content's default operation in sensenet

Tags: sensenet

I'm trying to change the content's default operation in document library, such as word, excel, ppt, default is preview, I want to change to download, but I can't find the way, could you give me some suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the value of the `ActionName` attribute to 'Browse' in /Root/System/SystemPlugins/ListView/Templates/ListView.xslt
Unfortunately ListViews are not automatically regenerated after the template modification, so to see the changes on the ui you have to save all the related ListViews again (go to `Views` folder under the related doclibs open the .ascx files for edit and without any modification save them).

Comment: Thanks for your reply! After I change the ActionName's value in template, the new work space's default action is changed. But for the exists work spaces, it doesn't work after I open and save the .ascx file. What I changed is Workspace1/Document_library/Views/Default.ascx(also Flat.ascx, Recent.ascx). Are there any other thing I should change?

Comment: All the old views in all the document libraries and workspaces should be  resaved.